# Select a nested text node with CSS?

Tags: html, css-selectors, shopify, selector, liquid

I'm trying to select a text node to change the font-size. I've tried to select everything inside the parent div and exclude everything but the text node using `:not()` with the hope it would work but nothing. Is there ANY way to select it somehow?

```html
<div class="grid-product__price"><span class="visually-hidden">Regular price</span>
  <span class="grid-product__price--original">$41.00</span>
  <span class="visually-hidden">Sale price</span>$19.00 // <---- trying to edit the 19
  <span class="grid-product__price--savings">Save $22.00</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You haven't shown what you did try. We can't help you debug that without it. [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the '$19.00' is actually plain text in the div, it may be easiest to just apply the style to the parent, and then revert it for the children.

### Example 1

```css
.grid-product__price{
  color: red
}

.grid-product__price span{
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-product__price"><span class="visually-hidden">Regular price</span>
  <span class="grid-product__price--original">$41.00</span>
  <span class="visually-hidden">Sale price</span>$19.00
  <span class="grid-product__price--savings">Save $22.00</span>
</div>
```

If that is not an option, try wrapping the text in a span tag and editing that.(see 'Update')

### Example 2

```css
.grid-product__price span {
  color: red;
}

.grid-product__price .savings{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-product__price"><span class="visually-hidden">Regular price</span>
  <span class="grid-product__price--original">$41.00</span>
  <span class="visually-hidden">Sale price</span><span class="savings">$19.00</span>
  <span class="grid-product__price--savings">Save $22.00</span>
</div>
```